# Minimal Go OpenGL Program Segmentation Fault

Tags: go, opengl

LearnOpenGL.com has a "Hello Window" tutorial [here](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Window).

At the end of the tutorial is a link to the source code [here](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/1.2.hello_window_clear/hello_window_clear.cpp). I've attempted to port that to Go. According to the tutorial the result should be a window with an unchanging flat color fill. Instead I get a segmentation fault. The stack trace points to this line:

```
gl.ClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0)
```

My questions are whether there is some GL state I have missed that must be set up before calling `gl.ClearColor` in a Go OpenGL program, and why does the C example work here while the Go example does not?

I'm running this code on Fedora 31 Desktop, Cinnamon Spin. My Go version is 1.13.7.

Minimal code to reproduce:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "runtime"

    "github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.3-core/gl"
    "github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw"
)

func init() {
    runtime.LockOSThread()
}

func KeyHandler(w *glfw.Window, key glfw.Key, scan int, action glfw.Action, mods glfw.ModifierKey) {
    if key == glfw.KeyEscape && action == glfw.Press {
        fmt.Println("Escape pressed")
        w.SetShouldClose(true)
    }
}

func Resize(w *glfw.Window, width int, height int) {
    gl.Viewport(0, 0, int32(width), int32(height))
}

func main() {
    err := glfw.Init()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer glfw.Terminate()
    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.ContextVersionMajor, 3)
    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.ContextVersionMinor, 3)
    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.OpenGLProfile, glfw.OpenGLCoreProfile)
    wwidth, wheight := 800, 600
    w, err := glfw.CreateWindow(wheight, wwidth, "example", nil, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create window: %s", err)
    }
    w.MakeContextCurrent()
    w.SetFramebufferSizeCallback(Resize)
    glfw.SwapInterval(1)
    w.SetKeyCallback(KeyHandler)
    for !w.ShouldClose() {
        gl.ClearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0)
        gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        w.SwapBuffers()
        glfw.PollEvents()
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x0]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x525f18, 0x2a)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:774 +0x72
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:378 +0x47c
runtime.asmcgocall(0x4761f1, 0x1)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:659 +0x70

goroutine 1 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.cgocall(0x4c51b0, 0xc000052eb8, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:128 +0x5b fp=0xc000052e88 sp=0xc000052e50 pc=0x4275db
github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.3-core/gl._Cfunc_glowClearColor(0x0, 0x3e99999a3e4ccccd, 0x3f8000003e99999a)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:3778 +0x45 fp=0xc000052eb8 sp=0xc000052e88 pc=0x4be1e5
github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.3-core/gl.ClearColor(...)
    /home/jrefior/home/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-gl/gl@v0.0.0-20190320180904-bf2b1f2f34d7/v3.3-core/gl/package.go:8700
main.main()
    /home/jrefior/home/opengl/window01/main.go:46 +0x235 fp=0xc000052f60 sp=0xc000052eb8 pc=0x4c4915
runtime.main()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203 +0x21e fp=0xc000052fe0 sp=0xc000052f60 pc=0x4505fe
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357 +0x1 fp=0xc000052fe8 sp=0xc000052fe0 pc=0x478cc1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not properly initializing the Go GL bindings. As the [documentation](https://github.com/go-gl/gl#usage) clearly states:

> ```
> import "github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.3-core/gl"
>
> func main() {
>   window := ... // Open a window.
>   window.MakeContextCurrent()
>
>   // Important! Call gl.Init only under the presence of an active OpenGL context,
>   // i.e., after MakeContextCurrent.
>   if err := gl.Init(); err != nil {
>       log.Fatalln(err)
>   }
> }
> ```

The init function will [query the function pointers for all GL functions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions) (which, on windows are dependent on the GL context, so it requires a current GL context). Note that the tutorial you linked uses `gladLoadGLLoader` for the same purpose, just via code generated by the [glad GL loader generator](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad).

Comment: Ah, I see now -- I had called `glfw.Init()` but missed `gl.Init()`. Thanks!